# Simple but topologizable

Tags: examples, topological-groups

Do you have an example of an infinite simple group with at least 3 distinct group topologies on it‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌?

Comment: $PSL_2(\mathbf{Q})$. It has infintely many group topologies, namely those induced by the embeddings $\mathbf{Q}\subset\mathbf{Q}_p$ where $p$ ranges over primes (possibly including $\mathbf{Q}_0=\mathbf{R}$ as well).

Comment: Since the discrete and the indiscrete topology are always compatible with the group structure, having three topologies isn't really that big of a requirement. In particular: Any (at least one-dimensional) group theoretically simple Lie-group will satisfy it.

Comment: @JohannesHahn: I didn't have an example of topologizable but Alexandrov non-topologizable. I'm not so familiar with Lie groups and matrix groups.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus You don't have to be "familiar". That real matrix groups are topological groups w.r.t. the euclidean topology is immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion take $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Then it has the topology as a matrix group over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. It has also the discrete topology. Finally you can embed $\mathbb{Q}_p$ in $\mathbb{C}$ (in many ways). So it has many topologies as a matrix group over $\mathbb{C}$. Now, you can divide by the centre and get $PSL(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. But I am not 100% sure that all of these topologies are distinct.